# Android VR Toolkit - HeadTransform getHeadView matrix representation

Tags: android, opengl-es, virtual-reality

I'm starting with Android VR-Toolkit for google cardboard.
I use the sample at google website:
https://developers.google.com/cardboard/get-started

I new with openGL and try to figure out how the values are represented by the system.
For example HeadTransform.getHeadView set a 4x4 matrix and according to the documentation:

> A matrix representing the transform from the camera to the head.
>   Head origin is defined as the center point between the two eyes.

My question is what represents every value (each cell) in the matrix?

Answer (score 2):

Google Cardboard 's headTransform.getHeadView() provide a transform matrix holding bothrotation and translation transforms (of the head).

Here is the matrix layout (column major order)

```
Rxx Ryx Rzx x
Rxy Ryy Rzy y
Rxz Ryz Rzz z
0    0    0 1
```

- [x, y, z] is the translation matrix. The vector is [0,0,0] in my tests.
- [Rxx, Rxy, Rxz] is the x axis after the rotation (replace Rx by Ry for the Y axis and so on).

Comment: He has clearly stated he is new to OpenGL and vrtoolkit and Eulerian matrix algebra. The best answer is to unburden the beginner from advanced complexity. There are many opengl frameworks (eg. Rajawali) that were created for exactly this reason, to allow people to manage the learning curves of opengl and its primitives. The question requires redirection: How best to work with vrtoolkit without apriori knowledge of OpenGL or Eulerian matrix algebra. Your answer does not help a beginner use vrtoolkit, it just burdens him with other steep learning curves which are not required to use vrtoolkit.

Comment: @Dominic Cerisano: The OP asked: "My question is what represents every value (each cell) in the matrix?". I provided the matrix layout, in the context of Android Cardboard / OpenGL. I will let the OP decide what answer/piece of information answers the question best.

Comment: The OP's primary line of interrogation (question) was:
"I new with openGL and try to figure out HOW the values are represented by the system.". As I pointed out, this is an interrogative (HOW does a newbie figure out to ...)
The question you answered was his secondary line of interrogation (another question). Just because the first did not end in a question mark does not mean it is not his primary line of interrogation. If he were not begging for general help in the first place, your answer to his specific but secondary request would be exemplary.

Comment: @DominicCerisano Here is my interpretation: 
- The OP's title is "Android VR Toolkit - HeadTransform getHeadView matrix representation". Therefore, "values are represented by the system" are in reference to "getHeadView"'s output.
- "I am new to OpenGL", He may simply confused by OpenGL slightly different matrix representation (column major order) compared to mathematical representation (row major order). Obviously I am speculating here, and you could as well be right.

Now, you are right. I did not help the OP to answer his/her own "HOW?" question, since I gave the OP the answer right away.

Comment: Since you admit I am right, why not remove your downvote? At no point did I say your answer is wrong: the OP asked two questions, which is bad form.

Comment: @DominicCerisano Lol! The OP wrote/asked 1 question. You deducted/found another one (I am not saying it is bad or good). Since the OP is the only one to know what he hoped to get when writing raising this post/question, I will let the OP decide about what kind of answer he hoped to get. Should he decide yours was a good one (even remotely good one), I will remove the downvote. Fair enough ? 

Alternatively, you could raise this issue on Meta SO and discuss it further there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new in OpenGL maybe vr toolkit is not the best place to start learning opengl.

You could find this interesting ftp://ftp.informatik.hu-berlin.de/pub3/Linux/Qt/QT/developerguides/qtopengltutorial/OpenGLTutorial.pdf

Comment: @Mahalakshmi why not?

Comment: The link seems broken :( 

Could you fix it?