# How to anchor an object using Cardboard Java SDK

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, google-cardboard, google-vr

I'm currently working on a project with the Cardboard SDK, and I'm relatively struck right now.

I want to display a cross in the center of the sight, like in a FPS, and keep it in the center of the sight when the user moves his head.

I know that in this code :

```
public void onNewFrame(HeadTransform headTransform) {
    float[] headView = new float[16];
    headTransform.getHeadView(headView, 0);
}
```

the headView param will contains the transformation matrix (rotation + translation) of the head (thanks to this SO : [Android VR Toolkit - HeadTransform getHeadView matrix representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085108/android-vr-toolkit-headtransform-getheadview-matrix-representation) ).

I tried to do this :

```
private float[] mHeadView = new float[16];

public void onNewFrame(HeadTransform headTransform) {
    headTransform.getHeadView(mHeadView, 0);
}

public void onDrawEye(Eye eye) {
    float[] mvpMatrix = new float[16];
    float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];
    float[] mvMatrix = new float[16];
    float[] camera = new float[16];
    Matrix.setLookAt(camera, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelMatrix, 0, mHeadView, 0, camera, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mvMatrix, 0, eye.getEyeView(), 0, modelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, eye.getEyePerspective(0.1, 100), 0, mvMatrix, 0);

    // Pass the mvpMatrix and vertices buffer to the vertex shader.
}
```

And here is my vertex shader :

```
uniform mat4 uMatrix;
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vColors;
varying vec4 color;
void main() {
    color = vColors;
    gl_Position = uMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

But the cross is still anchored to its initial position and doesn't follow the head.

Am I missing something ? 
How can I make my cross follow my head and stay in the center of the sight ?

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

(PS : I don't want to use Unity because this project must only use the Java SDK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: For a head-locked crosshair, skip the multiplication by the `mHeadView` matrix.

If you want a head locked object, you need to define it in head space, not in world space. Your current code defines the crosshair in world space. The `mHeadView` transform maps from world space to current head space, accounting for current head rotation. You don't need to multiply by this, it's only required for world-locked objects.